# How do you have a class change the value of an attribute of another class?

Tags: java, class, methods, attributes

Let's say I have a class named `Door` with an attribute that states whether it's *open* or *closed*. Then, there is another class named `Person`, that is assigned to that door.

How would you tell the person to open/close the door by changing the value of the attribute in the `Door` class with a method in the `Person` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```java
class Door {
    public boolean closed = true;
}

class Person {
    Door door = new Door();

    public void changeDoorState(boolean closed) {
        door.closed = closed;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i think this works but is there another way to do it where the boolean is private instead?

Comment: If you want the class `Person` to be able to access the boolean variable and change its value, it can't be private. However, in my example, the `door` variable from the `Person` class can be private. If you found my answer helpful, please consider marking it as 'accepted', thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `set` the door state, you can pass a value in a setter as follows. I would use an enum for this since it is more descriptive.

```
enum Door {
    CLOSED, OPEN
}
private Door door = Door.OPEN;

System.out.println(door);
changeDoorState();
System.out.println(door);
setDoorState(door.OPEN);
System.out.println(door);

public void setDoorState(Door status) {
    door = status;
}


public boolean isDoorOpen() {
    return door == Door.OPEN;
}

public Door getDoorState() {
     return door;
}
```

If you want to `change` the door state then do something like this.

```
public void changeDoorState() {
    // ternary - if door is open set to closed, else set to open
    door = door == Door.OPEN ? Door.CLOSED : Door.OPEN;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, unfortunately i dont rly understand this yet cuz im still a beginner since i just started learning java last night xD. thanks again tho!